# ffmpeg decoding on Android

Tags: android, video, android-ndk, ffmpeg, java-native-interface

I'm currently trying to use ffmpeg on Android. I built ffmpeg using https://github.com/halfninja/android-ffmpeg-x264 (I adapted it to not use libx264 and build with ndk-r9b, using GCC 4.6). I try to trim an MP4 file. However, the input file fails to open:

```
11-28 10:59:18.494: INFO/com.rfc.video.VideoKit(4125): ffmpeg
11-28 10:59:18.494: INFO/com.rfc.video.VideoKit(4125): -i
11-28 10:59:18.494: INFO/com.rfc.video.VideoKit(4125): /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/20131126_173903.mp4
11-28 10:59:18.494: INFO/com.rfc.video.VideoKit(4125): -ss
11-28 10:59:18.494: INFO/com.rfc.video.VideoKit(4125): 2
11-28 10:59:18.494: INFO/com.rfc.video.VideoKit(4125): -t
11-28 10:59:18.494: INFO/com.rfc.video.VideoKit(4125): 4
11-28 10:59:18.494: INFO/com.rfc.video.VideoKit(4125): -vcodec
11-28 10:59:18.494: INFO/com.rfc.video.VideoKit(4125): copy
11-28 10:59:18.494: INFO/com.rfc.video.VideoKit(4125): -acodec
11-28 10:59:18.494: INFO/com.rfc.video.VideoKit(4125): copy
11-28 10:59:18.494: INFO/com.rfc.video.VideoKit(4125): /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/trimmed-000-20131126_173903.mp4
11-28 10:59:18.494: INFO/com.rfc.video.VideoKit(4125): Running main
11-28 10:59:18.494: INFO/Videokit(4125): Initializing AV codecs
11-28 10:59:18.494: INFO/Videokit(4125): ffmpeg version 0.9.2, Copyright (c) 2000-2012 the FFmpeg developers
11-28 10:59:18.494: INFO/Videokit(4125): built on Nov 27 2013 15:38:26 with gcc 4.6 20120106 (prerelease)
11-28 10:59:18.494: INFO/Videokit(4125): configuration: --enable-cross-compile --arch=arm5te --enable-armv5te --target-os=linux --disable-stripping --prefix=../output --disable-neon --enable-version3 --ar=arm-linux-androideabi-ar --disable-shared --enable-static --enable-gpl --enable-memalign-hack --cc=arm-linux-androideabi-gcc --ld=arm-linux-androideabi-ld --extra-cflags='-fPIC -DANDROID -D__thumb__ -mthumb -Wno-deprecated' --disable-everything --enable-decoder=mjpeg --enable-demuxer=mjpeg --enable-parser=mjpeg --enable-demuxer=image2 --enable-muxer=mp4 --enable-decoder=rawvideo --enable-protocol=file --enable-hwaccels --disable-ffmpeg --disable-ffplay --disable-ffprobe --disable-ffserver --disable-network --enable-filter=buffer --enable-filter=buffersink --disable-demuxer=v4l --disable-demuxer=v4l2 --disable-indev=v4l --disable-indev=v4l2
11-28 10:59:18.494: INFO/Videokit(4125): libavutil    51. 32. 0 / 51. 32. 0
11-28 10:59:18.494: INFO/Videokit(4125): libavcodec   53. 42. 4 / 53. 42. 4
11-28 10:59:18.494: INFO/Videokit(4125): libavformat  53. 24. 2 / 53. 24. 2
11-28 10:59:18.494: INFO/Videokit(4125): libavdevice  53.  4. 0 / 53.  4. 0
11-28 10:59:18.494: INFO/Videokit(4125): libavfilter   2. 53. 0 /  2. 53. 0
11-28 10:59:18.494: INFO/Videokit(4125): libswscale    2.  1. 0 /  2.  1. 0
11-28 10:59:18.494: INFO/Videokit(4125): libpostproc  51.  2. 0 / 51.  2. 0
11-28 10:59:18.504: ERROR/Videokit(4125): /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/20131126_173903.mp4: Invalid data found when processing input
```

I digged into ffmpeg's code, and found the error:

```
static int opt_input_file(OptionsContext *o, const char *opt, const char *filename)
{

// ...

ic->video_codec_id   = video_codec_name ?
    find_codec_or_die(video_codec_name   , AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO   , 0)->id : CODEC_ID_NONE;
ic->audio_codec_id   = audio_codec_name ?
    find_codec_or_die(audio_codec_name   , AVMEDIA_TYPE_AUDIO   , 0)->id : CODEC_ID_NONE;
ic->subtitle_codec_id= subtitle_codec_name ?
    find_codec_or_die(subtitle_codec_name, AVMEDIA_TYPE_SUBTITLE, 0)->id : CODEC_ID_NONE;
ic->flags |= AVFMT_FLAG_NONBLOCK;
ic->interrupt_callback = int_cb;

if (loop_input) {
    LOGW(
        "-loop_input is deprecated, use -loop 1\n"
        "Note, both loop options only work with -f image2\n"
    );
    ic->loop_input = loop_input;
}

/* open the input file with generic avformat function */
err = avformat_open_input(&ic, filename, file_iformat, &format_opts);
if (err < 0) {
    print_error(filename, err);
    exit_program(1);
}
assert_avoptions(format_opts);

// ...

}
```

As indicated in the logcat, `err` is here equal to `AVERROR_INVALIDDATA`. I don't understand the reason however: the mp4 codec is enabled, as far as I can tell. Any hint on how to solve it?

Edit: I added more ffmpeg code. I'm pretty sure it's a codec issue now: ic->video_codec_id is set to `CODEC_ID_NONE`, which causes `ic` to be set to `NULL` and return a failure in `avformat_open_input()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was effectively a codec issue. Recompiling ffmpeg with libx264 support fixed this.